# Flutter - Phone Auth Verification ID is getting null sometimes for iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

My App got rejected 4th time in review from Apple team, they are saying App is crashing on tap of verify OTP button. They have shared a crash log, After checking the log I got to know that app is crashing due to null verification ID.

[image]

However everything is working perfectly locally and Android version is live, I have tested in real device & in emulator. Now I am not able to understand why verification ID is getting null sometime. I have already added try catch to handle exception, But that is not working in iOS, But working in Android.

Can someone please help me on this.

Below is the crash log...

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  9

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1ae904a48 0x1ae62bfa4 0x1ae8085a8 0x1ae908af4 0x1ae90aa7c 0x10264cc88 0x102648d58 0x1026489ec 0x1ae5d0610 0x1ae5d1184 0x1ae57d404 0x1ae57ddf8 0x1ae587314 0x1ae620b88 0x1ae623760)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ae6da634 0x1ae6d7000 + 13876
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ae6d9aa0 0x1ae6d7000 + 10912
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ae882288 0x1ae7d9000 + 692872
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ae87d3a8 0x1ae7d9000 + 672680
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ae87cadc 0x1ae7d9000 + 670428
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001b8802328 0x1b87ff000 + 13096
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b2977ae0 0x1b1f74000 + 10500832
7   Runner                          0x000000010263edf4 0x102638000 + 28148
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001ae706360 0x1ae705000 + 4960

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ae6da634 0x1ae6d7000 + 13876
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ae6d9aa0 0x1ae6d7000 + 10912
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ae882288 0x1ae7d9000 + 692872
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ae87d3a8 0x1ae7d9000 + 672680
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ae87cadc 0x1ae7d9000 + 670428
5   Foundation                      0x00000001aebbc7f4 0x1aebb5000 + 30708
6   Foundation                      0x00000001aebbc6d4 0x1aebb5000 + 30420
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b2a10204 0x1b1f74000 + 11125252
8   Foundation                      0x00000001aeced0a4 0x1aebb5000 + 1278116
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ae61fd8c 0x1ae615000 + 44428
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ae62376c 0x1ae615000 + 59244
```